# How do I get this php form to work?

Tags: php, forms

Ive got a contact form thats using the same php code on another website and it works great, but on this one it will not work for some reason, after clicking send, it redirects me to a blank page saying "No Arguments Provided!". Below is the html and php for the form.

```
<!-- Contact form -->
    <section id="contact_form">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2> We would love to hear about your upcoming project.</h2>
                    <h2 class="second_heading">Get In Touch With Us!</h2>
                </div>
                <form role="form" class="form-inline text-right col-md-6" method="post" action="mail/contact_us.php" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn submit_btn">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- Contact form end -->

<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
empty($_POST['email'])      ||
empty($_POST['msg'])    ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];

// create email body and send it
$to = 'myemail@address.com'; // send to: email
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact 
form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: 
$email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@myemail.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your form inputs/textareas are missing the `name` attribute. For example:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

Needs to be

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
```

The `name` attribute is what's used when submitting a form, so as you have it, PHP isn't seeing the form fields.

Comment: ill try this and let you know if it solves the issue, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: crazy how such a small instance can keep an entire form from sending. Kudos to @j08691